# First node stays on top

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I want the first node to stay on top and should not be affected during scroll. The first node will be like a column header(stays on top even scrolling). How can I do that?

This kind of behavior is something you can currently find in spreasheets:

- Lock first column *(`Header`.`Columns[0]`.`Options` → `coFixed`)*
- Lock first row *(?)*

I'm trying to insert a picture for more explanation but I don't have 10 reputations. Sorry about that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as VirtualTree doesn't support such a behaviour. Besides, VT already has header support (include `hoVisible` to `Header.Options` to show it) why don't you use that? You can custom paint it (see `OnHeaderDraw` events) if you want it to look like ordinary node.